# XCode can''t find header of 3rd party library

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks, ensembles

I'm trying to add the Ensembles 2 framework to my iOS project (switching from the open source Ensembles 1, v2 is not open source so I don't have access to the code or cocoa pod anymore).

I think I followed the install instructions to the point:

1. Dragged in the framework (and the .bundle)
2. Made sure targets and "copy items" are selected
3. Made sure -ObjC is set

XCode copies the framework to $(PROJECT_DIR) which is also set in *Framework Search Paths* (among other dirs). It seems to be unable to find `<Ensembles/Ensembles.h>` though, no matter what I try. I searched similar questions on SO and elsewhere and tried various combinations of *Framework Search Path* settings and *Header Search Path* settings but have had no success so far. Specifically I tried

- Adding and removing quotes from existing *Framework Search Path* settings
- Playing with the *recursive* setting
- Creating a *Frameworks* subdirectory and adding the framework there. Then add `"$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks` to *Framework Search Paths* and *Header Search Paths* (both recursive and non-recursive)
- Adding `"$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/Ensembles/Headers"` to *Header Search Paths*
- Deleting, cleaning, and re-adding the framework multiple times

This is getting frustrating. Any other ideas? I'm using XCode 7.2.1 btw.

Comment: Did you try importing "Ensembles.h" instead of <Ensembles/Ensembles.h>?

Comment: Looks to me like what you've tried should work.  I am surprised the path was `Frameworks/Ensembles/` and not `Frameworks/Ensembles.framework/`, however.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to have been an XCode issue, probably some cached intermediate files or something. To resolve I

1. Went to *File* -> *Workspace Settings...* to find the build directory
2. Quit XCode
3. Deleted everything in the build directory
4. Restarted XCode, recompiled, et voila...